# How to click on the submit botton & handle the download notification using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

```
Sub Drop_Down()
Dim objIE As Object, ele As Object, opt As Object
Dim y As Integer
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIE.Visible = True
    source = "http://pipeline.wyo.gov/rCountyProdnSalesByYear_menu.cfm?Oops=#oops#&RequestTimeOut=6500"
    objIE.navigate source

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    Set ele = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")

    For Each opt In ele
        If opt.getAttribute("name") = "bCode" Then
            opt.Focus
            opt.Value = "003"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next opt

Set ele = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")

    For Each opt In ele
        If opt.getAttribute("name") = "nYr" Then
            opt.Focus
            opt.Value = "2015"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next opt

Set ele = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("td")

    For Each opt In ele
        If opt.getAttribute("TYPE") = "Submit" Then
            opt.Focus
            opt.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next opt
objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are two different types of automation one of which is a web-driver styled automation which allows you to force commands through the web-page, another is designed for windows notifications/programs which arent web-based, such as a download notification.

I think you're going to have to record the action on another program and some-how try to import the script it records to be ran when you run your automation tests, otherwise there will be some backwards way of getting there, i'm sure someone on here will know.

For e.g. https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=32323

That guy has got AutoHotKey + Selenium working together, i've not done anything but it's possible.

All the best,
Jack